# How to get data from 1 table and insert into another table after doing mathematical operation

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 table i.e `AccPurchase` and `PurchaseProjection`. There is already data in AccPurchase and i want to get data from AccPurchase and after adding some percentage and then insert into PurchaseProjection Table. I have html form and i am sending Date and Percentage value from form. I have add some percentage to every single row of selected Date and insert into PurchaseProjection.

```
<?php
$date = $_GET['1'];
$percentage = $_GET['2'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pw","db");

$sql = "Select Date, Amount, Paid, Outstanding from 
AccPurchase Where Date='$date'";
$row = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
mysqli_fetch_array($row,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$date=$row['Date'];
$amount=$row["Amount*('$percentage'/100)"];
$paid=$row['Paid'];
$outstanding=$row['Outstanding'];

$sql1 = "INSERT into PuchaseProjection (`Date`,`Amount`,`Paid`,`Outstanding`) VALUES ('$date','$amount','$paid','$outstanding')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

mysqli_close($con);;

 ?>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting with this code

Comment: It sounds like you're just looking for examples of how to use `mysqli_fetch_array()`?  Have you looked at the documentation?: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php  Also, be aware that your code is wide open to **SQL injection**.  You should be using prepared statements and treating user input as *values*, not as *executable code*.

Comment: 0
down vote

I recommand you to use PDO for MySQL Operations. for your question i have solution that i also use in my projects. just put select query after insert query with same column name and column count and it will work like a charm.

QUERY : INSERT into PuchaseProjection (Date,Amount,Paid,Outstanding) Select Date, Amount, Paid, Outstanding from AccPurchase Where Date=?

Comment: Yes i tried this before but how can i add opration on Amount Column? @KunalAwasthi

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT into PuchaseProjection (Date,Amount,Paid,Outstanding) Select Date, Amount+(Amount*'$percentage'/100), Paid, Outstanding From AccPurchase Where Date='$date'"; `  i tried this @KunalAwasthi

Comment: `$sql = "INSERT into PuchaseProjection (Date,Amount,Paid,Outstanding) Select Date, Amount+(Amount*'$percentage'/100) as Amount, Paid, Outstanding From AccPurchase Where Date='$date'";` try this one @user10004678

Comment: Perfact. Thank its workings @KunalAwasthi

Comment: welcom happy to help can i post it as answer.

Comment: @user10004678 i posted my answer.

Comment: Bobby Tables is going to get you unless you harden your code against SQL injection.  http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommand you to use PDO for MySQL Operations.
for your question i have solution that i also use in my projects. just put select query after insert query with same column name and column count and it will work like a charm.

**QUERY :**
`INSERT into PuchaseProjection (Date,Amount,Paid,Outstanding) Select Date, Amount+(Amount * :percentage / 100) as Amount, Paid, Outstanding from AccPurchase Where Date=:date`

:percentage and :date means placeholder in a pdo statement.Visit [PDO Official Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
 <?php
 $date = $_GET['1'];
 $percentage = $_GET['2'];
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","pw","db");

 $sql = "Select Date, Amount, Paid, Outstanding from 
 AccPurchase Where Date='$date'";
 $row = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 mysqli_fetch_array($row,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 $date=$row['Date']/*do the operation,if any*/;
 $amount=$row["Amount"]*($percentage/100);
  $paid=$row['Paid']/*do the operation,if any*/;
  $outstanding=$row['Outstanding']/*do the operation,if any*/;

  $sql1 = "INSERT into PuchaseProjection 
  (`Date`,`Amount`,`Paid`,`Outstanding`) VALUES 
  ('$date','$amount','$paid','$outstanding')";
  mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
   mysqli_close($con);

  ?>
```

try this

Comment: Check i performed operation on Amount but its not working. I updated my code in question.

Comment: status code 500 after this. Something is wrong in $amount variable. Also check i added 1 query in comments.

Comment: print and see the value of $amount immediately after the `$amount=$row["Amount"]*($percentage/100);`

Comment: also `$row['Amount']` must be a string and thats why the operation cannot be performed.